# Displaying Multidimensional Arrays in Java

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Things start here
    int[][] multi = new int[5][10];
    for(int p = 1; p < 5; p++)
    {
        for(int h = 1;h < 10;h++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the score for Player " + String.valueOf(p) + ", Hole " + String.valueOf(h) + " :");           

            String v = stringReader();
            multi[p][h] = Integer.parseInt(v);
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(v));
        }
    }   
}
public static String stringReader()
{
    String value;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
    value = bufferedReader.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    value = "0";
    }
    return value;
}
```

Hello! I am currently working on a project for my Grade 12 Computer Science course where i am asked to make a "Golf Score Tracker" the description of the project is (add to the code below code that calculates and displays each golfers individual score)

I've tried working with while loops however whatever I do it does not seem to display. My teacher is also stuck lol he is actually the reason I am here asking for help on this project

Comment: input, output, desired output?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html